# How frame Json object dynamically with dynamic key and value strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

i have a json 
i want to add key value pairs (after framing the below format) like

```
var json = {};
var a = '"key1" : "value1"'; //coming as dynamic
var b = '"key2" : "value2"'; // coming as dynamic
json.push(a); // i know it is wrong.
json.push(b); // i know it is wrong.
console.log(json); // {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"} expected

var array = [];
var c = '{"key1": "value1"}';
var d = '{"key2": "value2"}';
array.push(c);
array.push(d);
console.log(array); // ["{"key1": "value1"}", "{"key2": "value2"}"]
```

like the above i can push objects to array, but how can i push json strings directly to a json object.

Comment: try this `array["key1"] = "value"`

Comment: Do you get var a = '"key1" : "value1"'; dynamically as a string ?

Comment: @SSH There's no associative arrays in JS

Comment: "Unfortunately rather than taking dynamic value it is taking the reference variable itself " What do you mean by this?

Comment: Thankyou @SSH, Ravi, Rory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly a little clarification; there's no such thing as a 'JSON object'. There is a JSON-formatted string, and there is an object. They are two separate entities.

To add strings to an object, specify the property of the object and set its value. You don't need `push()` for this as that is used exclusively for arrays. In your case, it should look like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.key1 = "value1";
obj.key2 = "value2";
console.log(obj); // = { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }
```

To set a key dynamically use bracket notation:

```
var key = 'foo';
obj[key] = 'bar';
console.log(obj); // = { 'foo': 'bar' }
```

If you need to then convert the object to a JSON string, call `JSON.stringify` on that object:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Also note that in your second example you end up with an array of strings, not an array of objects. If you want an array of objects you need to remove the quotes around the values you set, like this:

```
var array = [];
var c = { "key1": "value1" };
var d = { "key2": "value2" };
array.push(c);
array.push(d);
console.log(array); // [{ "key1": "value1" }, { "key2": "value2" }]
```

Note the difference in the position of the quotes in the objects and the result from the console.

Comment: var obj = {};
obj.key1 = "value1";
obj.key2 = "value2";
console.log(obj); // = { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }

key1 and key2 values are coming dynamically, in the loop i am trying to fetch the values and setting to keys. Unfortunately rather than taking dynamic value it is taking the reference variable itself due to it finally one value is there in output of json by overrriding it self.

for(var i=0; i<3;i++){
 var a='key'+i;
 obj.a = "value"+1;
}

console.log(obj); // = Object {a: "value1"}

Comment: For dynamic keys your answer is not enough. Can you polish it if possible.
@Rory

Comment: Use bracket notation. I added an example of that for you

Comment: Acc. to http://json.org/ JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format which is a text format with 2 structure :- a) A collection of name/value pairs as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array. b) An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Comment: Exactly - it's just called 'JSON', not a 'JSON object'